# Renaming placed containers

Tags: bukkit

I'm just wondering is there a way to give or rename a container like chest that is already on ground?

I mean not using NMS. But the spigot API to edit the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for it but it is possible with NMS. I made this method some time ago, it allows you to name any tile entity.

You give it a normal bukkit block and name that will be applied to the block. Name can have § coloring char.

With this code you can make version using reflections if you want to avoid NMS and CB imports.

```
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.INamableTileEntity;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityBrewingStand;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityChest;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityCommand;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityDispenser;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityEnchantTable;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityFurnace;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.TileEntityHopper;

import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftWorld;

public static void setName(String name, Block block) {
    final CraftWorld world = (CraftWorld) block.getWorld();
    final TileEntity nmsTileEntity = world.getTileEntityAt(block.getX(), block.getY(), block.getZ());

    if (nmsTileEntity instanceof INamableTileEntity) {
        if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityChest) {
            ((TileEntityChest) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityFurnace) {
            ((TileEntityFurnace) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityDispenser) {
            ((TileEntityDispenser) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityHopper) {
            ((TileEntityHopper) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityBrewingStand) {
            ((TileEntityBrewingStand) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityEnchantTable) {
            ((TileEntityEnchantTable) nmsTileEntity).a(name);
        } else if (nmsTileEntity instanceof TileEntityCommand) {
            ((TileEntityCommand) nmsTileEntity).getCommandBlock().setName(name);
        }

        nmsTileEntity.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out this isn't working in 1.7, it seems 1.7 didn't have "INamableTileEntity"